# Generating a self signed certificate using TLSv1.2 or 1.1

Tags: java, ssl, keytool, tls1.2, tls1.1

I have a business server i am trying to connect to using java,but to do that they demand the Tls version be either `1.1` or `1.2`.

I have openssl installed in my computer and i seem to be using Tls version 1.1. I i tested my openssl installation with this command

`openssl s_client -host google.com -port 443`

and this is the result

```
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: FFE6DD3F1F78EC17999809D875E12D5138573BE52BCAA2EB55225F2EFE864127
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 7599DC1A0FDC8BC41431D7907EE933BE7527D2A658ADFC6B34B2CAB3D071DD7E13B6ED2C7C35A6EABDCA52943B1155A2
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1489987373
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

some info has been left out for readability purposes but you can test out in your terminal.

This is my java version

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

How can i make my java keytool to generate a certificate with a `Tls` version `1.1` or `1.2`?.

Comment: TLS is a data security layer, and not a certificate property. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

What you are looking for is `SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate should be immaterial of the transport.

Without knowing what you are using for the server side, it will be a bit difficult to determine what your best course of action should be.

You can force s_client into using *just* tls 1.2 by passing the -tls1_2 switch, but that is not really what you want.

So, say you were using Tomcat 8 (and the non-APR HTTP connector), you could configure for just TLSv1.2 using the attribute sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2".

The sslEnabledProtocols essentially maps to the SSLSocket.setEnabledProtocols() method of Java. Jetty probably has a similar configuration.

If you are using Apache HTTPd or nginx, there is probably documentation that will state how to do that as well.

Comment: "The certificate should be immaterial of the transport." so a pubic key generated using t.l.s 1.2 will work on any machine say with tls 1.0?

Comment: When generating your private key and self signed cert, there is no requirement to specify a transport algorithm.